# Issue with if statement variable

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am trying to create this simple if statement, but I am running into issues with the variable `$testnumrows`. In this if condition I am trying to see if there are any `group` columns with data and if so echo the amount of rows, but I want nothing to show up if there isn't.

In my db I have 6 rows that have what I mentioned in the query. The output that is showing up on the page is 0 though, so it seems my variable is being reset.

Before I had this:

```
$testnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($test);
echo " " . $testnumrows;
```

and it read the 6, I just can't get the if statement to work.

Here is the full code now.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$test = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `group` FROM user_requests WHERE `group` = 1");
$testnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($test);

if($testnumrows = 0) {
echo "";
} else {
echo " " . $testnumrows;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong equals: `$testnumrows = 0`, `=`is for assignment. Try `$testnumrows === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should read `if($testnumrows == 0) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial error `=` instead of `==`
Solution:

```
if($testnumrows == 0) {
echo "";
} else {
echo " " . $testnumrows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change if($testnumrows = 0) to if($testnumrows == 0).